# Highlight all occurence of the selection

Tags: vim, plugins

i'm creating a little function in order to highlight same term as you are currently selected in Visual mode.

that's my current work :

```
function CheckSameTerm()

    let currentmode = mode()

    " Check for (any) visual mode
    if currentmode =~? '.*v'

        exec printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))

        "this method is for selection only and not full word(but don't really work) 
        "let select = getline("'<")[getpos("'<")[2]-1:getpos("'>")[2]-1]
        "exec printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', select)

    endif

endfunction

au CursorMoved * exec "call CheckSameTerm()"
```

For now i'm quite stuck with 2 issues :

- the code actually check full word > escape(expand(''), '/\') because I can't get the exact selected text.
- I have to find a way to delete highlight on visual leave (but no event exist for that)

So have you some ideas for that ? And most important question : Do I go on the good way ? Maybe I miss something easier.

oh and by the way, this is to learn vim script, it is not life saver ;)

**Edit**

This plugin evolved, go check https://github.com/Losams/-VIM-Plugins/blob/master/checkSameTerm.vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right way. This is far beyond trivial Vim customization, though, and to turn this into a robust plugin, a lot more work is required.

To address your questions:

- The `'<,'>` marks unfortunately only contain the current selection once you've *left* visual mode (explicitly or after operating on it). Your code for extracting the text is fine, but the marks aren't set yet. Instead, you can `y`ank the current selection and then restore it with `gv`. This clobbers the default register; additional code to save / restore its contents would be needed. (See [`ingo#selection#Get()`](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/master/autoload/ingo/selection.vim#L15) from my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) for a robust implementation.)
- As the visual selection is not necessarily delimited by keyword boundaries, you need to drop the `\<` ... `\>` from the pattern.
- To handle selections across lines, embedded newline characters need to be converted into the `\n` atom. I do this with `substitute()` after escaping the special characters in the selection.
- `mode()` returns `v`, `V`, or `^V` for visual mode. No need for the `.*` and pattern matching; `^V` also is a single character (and we cannot handle blockwise selections in a good way, anyway, so it's best to ignore it).
- To turn off highlighting, just add an `else` block to the conditional. It needs an additional cursor move to apply, though.
- You don't need `:execute` in the `:autocmd`; there are no variables here that need to be interpolated.

Here's what I have:

```
function! CheckSameTerm()
    let currentmode = mode()
    " Check for (any) visual mode
    if currentmode ==? 'v'
        normal! ygv
        exec printf('match IncSearch /\V%s/', substitute(escape(@", '/\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g'))
    else
        match none
    endif
endfunction
au! CursorMoved * call CheckSameTerm()
```

I hope this helps you with a further exploration of Vim scripting. Have fun!

Comment: That's so great thanks for the complete answer i understand now why I got a delay step on my '<,'> (I was suspected that but i was not sure). The match none is great but isn't it quite "heavy" to do that on every move ?

Comment: You could set a flag variable instead and skip the `match none` then, but I doubt that it would make a difference. The C implementation presumably just checks an internal data structure, realizes there's no current match, and then exits.

Comment: I put the yank on an other register ('c') to keep my previous working yank. I add also a cursorHold to "bypass" a little the visualLeave event missing. It is not perfect but...  here is the beast : https://github.com/Losams/-VIM-Plugins/blob/master/checkSameTerm.vim

Comment: Using a different register will also alias the default register to its contents (at least for me). `CursorHold` is one option, right.

Comment: Strangely it seems to keep my default register in "current" yank for me.